# How to make a function repeat while a key is held

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to using unity and I am trying to write a script which allows the player to pick up a petrol can and pour it out. Ive been looking everywhere, but I can not find a solution to the rate at which the petrol pours when you press the F key or the few ones which may work are hard to understand. (This is a first person 3D game by the way.)

The script checks if the player is moving and if the key is held down then use InvokeRepeating to repeat the spawn function. To check if the can is moving the script gets the last position in a FixedUpdate(using Update didn't make a difference) and compares it to the current position.
This script only partially works and the petrol png spawn rate is very inconsistent.
Also making a script that checks the players movement wouldn't work because moving the camera w/ the mouse moves the petrol as well.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LiquidHoldScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    pop_up pickupToggle;
    cakeslice.Outline inRangeOutline;
    Ray spawnRay;
    RaycastHit spawnLoc;

    public GameObject player;
    public Transform holdPos;
    public float pickUpRange = 2.5f;
    public GameObject PickUpUI;
    public GameObject splash;
    public cakeslice.Outline destOutline;
    public float pourFreq = 0f;

    private bool canHold;
    private bool canPour;
    private bool isHeld;
    private bool isVisible;
    private bool canPickUIHide;
    private float playerDistance;
    private bool isMoving;
    private float lastX;
    private float lastY;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        inRangeOutline = GetComponent<cakeslice.Outline>();
        pickupToggle = PickUpUI.GetComponent<pop_up>();

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (lastX != transform.position.x && lastY != transform.position.y)
        {
            Debug.Log("Moving");
            lastX = transform.position.x;
            lastY = transform.position.y;
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Aint moving");
            isMoving = false;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        playerDistance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (isVisible && playerDistance <= pickUpRange)
        {
            canPickUIHide = true;
            if (isHeld)
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F) && isMoving)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Oilin up");
                    InvokeRepeating("SpawnPetrol", 0.001f, 1f);
                }
                else
                {
                    CancelInvoke("SpawnPetrol");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.Log("Force Shown pick/drop ui");
                pickupToggle.ForceShow();
                inRangeOutline.eraseRenderer = false;
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
                {
                    isHeld = true;
                    hold();
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (canPickUIHide)
            {
                //hides UI when criteria unmet
                pickupToggle.ForceHide();
                inRangeOutline.eraseRenderer = true;
                canPickUIHide = false;
                //Debug.Log("Thang not visible n pickmissive")
            }

        }

    }

    void SpawnPetrol()
    {

        spawnRay = new Ray(transform.position, -Vector3.up);
        if (Physics.Raycast(spawnRay, out spawnLoc))
        {
            Instantiate(splash, spawnLoc.point + new Vector3(0f, 0.0001f, 0f), splash.transform.rotation);
        }

    }

    void hold()
    {
        
        transform.position = holdPos.transform.position;
        transform.rotation = holdPos.transform.rotation;
        transform.parent = holdPos.transform;

        inRangeOutline.eraseRenderer = true;

    }

    void OnBecameVisible()
    {
        isVisible = true;
    }
    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        isVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Invoke/InvokeRepeting` are usually avoided. One they are a bit heavy but most importantly they use `string` as parameter. Say you rename your `SpawnPetrol` method to `SpawnPetrols` then your invoke will no longer work with no errors or anything that will tell you that there is a problem. You can semi-fix this by replacing `"SpawnPetrol"` with `nameof(SpawnPetrol)` but better replace invoking with direct call in `Update` or coroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this a bit.

Something as simple as this would work to repeatedly call a funciton as a button is held

```
Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
    {
        SpawnPetrol();
    }
}
```

But, if you want that one second delay then you would be best to use a coroutine that will wait 1 second between invocations

```
Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnPetrolCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator SpawnPetrolCoroutine()
{
    while(true) // do this forever
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F)
        {
            SpawnPetrol();
            yield return new WaitforSeconds(1); // wait one second until will try to spawn again
        }   

        yield return null;     
    }
}
```

Using unity's `Invoke` methods are overkill when calling local functions, you're better to just... call them :)

Comment: Thank you for the response, however there are a few significant issues with your version of the script: 
1. The code simply crashes unity the moment I press play. I tried removing other parts of the script, but they dont change much . Also the first script I had tried beforehand however that aswell crashed unity, this time after pressing the F key while the can is held. This is most likely from the game having to spawn an object each update.
2.(There is a character limit in stack overflow so I will post the 2nd issue in a few minutes inside of another comment after this one.)

Comment: 2. Your code wouldn't work most likely as needed because I need the script to check if multiple things including if the player is moving and if the can is held so I need the game to start spawning the petrol object with 1 second inbetween each spawn while the key is held and stop when it has been let go.
3. I belive the main problem was that the movement sensing was too fast so the isMoving boolean kept chaning its state and disrupting the Invoke by cancelling it.

Comment: You asked how to repeat a function call when you're holding a key down. @Jay told you how to do so. How about you create a new script with just an update function, an input check and a debug log. See if that works (it will) and work from there.

Comment: @CrazyDawg no you are correct, apologies I did not have the chance to test the code I wrote. A `yield return null` was required within the non-happy path of the while loop. The corrected code will work

Comment: @CrazyDawg As for the rest of your points, you can simply add the rest of your requirements on top of the technique i have described :) The SO community will help you solve problems and fix structural issues but we don't know your domain and might not be able to provide you with the full exact code you need.  If you are having trouble adapting a provided solution to your project then please open another question and we'll be happy to help :)

Comment: note that this way you can spam the key and avoid the cooldown ;)

Comment: @derHugo not tested... but can you? Would the yield return waitForSeconds not act as a cooldown? its not going to even test for input again for 1s?

Comment: @Jay yes! my bad sorry, you are totally right of course! Once it entered the `if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F)` it will definitely wait for the `yield return new WaitforSeconds(1);` ... you could even put the `yield return null;` into an `else` block